# Bash:cd:No such folder or directory , but it exists

Tags: command-line, bash, cd-command

I am new in ubuntu and I am doing a project where i should install the charm crypto library in my android device.In the manual file it says that i should create two folders: $BD and $SCRIPTS.
I created them on my Desktop so after the command cd Desktop I tried to execute the following command:
`cd $BD/android-python27 && $SCRIPTS/python.sh`, but i get the error

```
bash: cd: /android-python27: No such file or directory
```

I should mention that inside $BD folder the folder android-python27 exists.So does anybody know how i can solve this issue?

Comment: I think you need a `./` before `$BD`

Comment: Did you actually assign a value to the variable `BD`? it looks like `$BD` is expanding to the empty string `""`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$BD is an environment variable.  If "$BD" is actually the name of your directory, you should rename the directory.  If for some reason you can't, you can address it by making the entire pathname literal with single-quotes ('), thus:

```
cd '$BD/android-python27' && '$SCRIPTS/python.sh'
```

If $BD is in fact supposed to be a variable, it is undefined, and you need to set it, thus:

```
export BD=/path/to/container/directory/
```

Comment: Your suggestion actually worked but there is another prolem.After the cd i moved inside the android-python27 directory but there is a new error:$scripts/python.sh: No such file or directory. This is actually true because the directory $SCRIPTS is inside $BD folder.But how i can execute succesfully this command?

Comment: It's hard to say because you didn't say which part worked?  Different answer depending.

Comment: I renamed the directories to bd and scripts.The command I use is for building the dependecies.

Comment: Oh, good.  Now set the SCRIPTS variable to the fully qualified pathname of .../scripts.  EG: export SCRIPTS=$BD/scripts/ or /full/path/to/scripts/.  Don't forget that bash is case-sensitive.  $SCRIPTS <> $scripts.